# Is it possible to nest index-match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm looking for a way to return a value for the following data in excel:

```
                       -----------------
                       |  Jan  |  Feb  |
----------------------------------------
| Area1 | Func1 Target | 300.0 | 250.0 |
| Area1 | Func2 Target | 250.0 | 230.0 |
| Area1 | Func3 Target | 30.0  | 50.0  |
| Area2 | Func1 Target | 250.0 | 300.0 |
| Area2 | Func2 Target | 35.0  | 60.0  |
----------------------------------------
```

I need to pull the target for a particular area and function for a specific month automatically,  I already know how to do a match based on Area and Month but I can't seem to figure out how to match based of Area & Function Target based on month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this array formula¹,

```
=INDEX(C$2:D$6, MATCH(1, (A$2:A$6=F4)*(B$2:B$6=G4), 0), MATCH(H4, C$1:D$1, 0))
```

[image: two_column_match_row_match]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Err I spoke too soon, for me it's only grabbing the first return value and that's it and randomly displays #N/A errors...

Comment: If you are looking to get the second, third match to Area1|Func3|Jan then you would have to use AGGREGATE, not MATCH. Unfortunately, teh data currently doesn't support that scenario. This may also be a new question since the requirement breaks the existing answer.

Comment: I actually goofed on the live data I was using, didn't know the "Area1" part has some spaces in it >.<  The original answer is actually valid and works for that scenario.

Thanks again Jeeped!